Remote Desktop - Can't access Ubuntu 24.04 from Windows 10 client
I've tried to set up Remote Desktop to access my Ubuntu 24.04 machine from a windows 10 laptop on the same network.
I've gone to Settings>System>Remote Desktop and enabled it under the Remote Login tab. I've set a username and password in there too. I've restarted the computer for good measure after enabling Remote Desktop.
When I try to access my Ubuntu PC from the Windows 10 Remote Desktop client it looks like it tries to connect (even asks for my password), but then pops up with the message box 'An authentication error has occurred. More data is available. Remote computer: 192.168.1.200'.
I can't quite figure out what I have done wrong. It looks like it should be simple enough.
Any help appreciated :)
Stephen
Additional information for further clarification requested:

I'm going for Remote Desktop (i.e. when I'm locally logged out)
I do not have automatic login (i.e. I do get a login screen on boot) and I do not log in from that screen when trying to access by Remote Desktop.


I've edited my original question with the additional clarification requested :)

You may want to try the "Original Answer" part of this answer. Let me know in a comment if xrdp works for you.

you might have a different issue (the error I had was We couldn't connect to the remote PC. This might be due to an expired password. 0x207), but if you are using Microsoft Remote Desktop try the use redirection fix

Frequently I find that Network Level Authentication that is blocking the connection. When connecting, select show options, then the advanced tab and then verify that "If server authentication fails" is set to either "warn me" (recommended) or to "connect and don't warm me".

Hi Tony. Thank you for your suggestion. The option was set to "warn me", but I've tried setting it to "connect and don't warn me" to see if it changes anything. Unfortunately I still get the same error from my Windows 10 client as before :(
